# Sparrow or Cocos2D for iPhone 2D game?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sparrow-framework

I want to develop a game for iPhone. For 2D game development in iPhone which one of these would be better in the long run....Sparrow or Cocos2D? I've seen that there is a scarce documentation for Sparrow framework but Sparrow forum says it is easier to develop games in Sparrow as compared to Cocos2D. So, where should i start with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocos2d-iPhone or Sparrow for first time 2D iOS game development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605609/cocos2d-iphone-or-sparrow-for-first-time-2d-ios-game-development)

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199773/best-iphone-framework-for-2d-platform-games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d is thoroughly developed, and there are several books and a myriad of forums on the subject. I don't know too much about Sparrow. "Easy" is a relative term. If I were you, learn cocos2d.

**Edit:** since this question was asked, there's Apple's SpriteKit and a game engine I've built called [MBTileParser](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBTileParser).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've done a lot of surfing on the net & finally decided to go with Cocos2D.

Answer (score 4):

Both look pretty good for basic 2D development but Cocos2D seems a bit more mature (though Sparrow does seem to have a good start.

Another potential consideration is portability. The cocos2d API has been ported to android but Sparrow hasn't.

Comment: The cocos2d android port is weak from what I understand. AndEngine is a good Android game framework, according to a friend who I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

If your game is making use of large amount of animation, most likely that Cocos2D is your friend. It is because Cocos2D supports PVRTC texture which reduce memory usage. PVRTC is an image format. When it is loaded into RAM, it consumes less memory at the expense of image quality. PVRTC is not  yet supported in the current version of Sparrow.