# Sprites for iOS devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to do a little research for my next game that I'm planning to make and just wondering if anyone could give me a little direction.

I'd like to use sprites to show animation, characters walking and such so my question is this. What game engine handles sprites the best?

And how many sprites can be shown per second? Say i had a character walking and wanted it to look pretty fluid, might i be able to get 60fps? or is that way way to high?

Last question.. sorry! If a sprite has more colors and complexity, but is the same file size as something simpler would it take more processing power to display the complex one?

thanks!
James.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) for sprite animations. It's very easy to pick up if you already know objective-c. And it's great for working with sprites. The animations are very fluid and when your testing your applications in an iOS simulator, it tells you the frames per second in the bottom left hand corner. The frames per second usually runs at about 60. And regarding the  sprite file size, I believe if the file size is the same between two sprites then they require the same amount of processing power.

Comment: Cocos2d is good but it's a lot more complicated to use than Sparrow.  If the OP is just wanting to display sprites (with perhaps alpha, rotation and scaling) Sparrow is more than sufficient and a LOT easier to use.

Comment: @Cthutu Either one will work honestly. Cocos 2d is really not that complicated though. With a couple good tutorials, I created a basic game with some animation in a day. Plus, if you get stuck, it's a lot easier to find help with cocos 2d. Here's a good [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624553/sparrow-or-cocos2d-for-iphone-2d-game) on sparrow vs cocos2d.

Comment: I've published games with both but I prefer Sparrow and the community is more helpful, but your mileage might vary.  As Mike said, either one will work.

Answer (score 0):

A good engine to use for it's simplicity is the [Sparrow engine](http://gamua.com/sparrow/) for sprites, sound and other things.  There is no reason you can't get 60fps.  As for your last question, it wouldn't make a difference.