# iphone/ipad game development

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-engine

I'm a iOS developer. I have developed many apps for iPhone and iPad. Now planning to start with game development. I need few details before starting with it??

1. How different is game development from appl. development?
2. Any extra training required for gamin?
3. Is 2D gaming possible with just Objective C??
4. what search engines or libraries should i use for 2D/3D games?
5. any tutorials or books for game development?
6. Will gaming work purely on Objective C? or other languages like C/C++ needs to be used?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: You're asking over six questions here, so you're going to need to narrow the scope of this a bit. Several of these questions have been asked here before in different forms, such as in [Best iPhone framework for 2D platform games](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199773/best-iphone-framework-for-2d-platform-games). Also, something like "How different is game development from appl. development" is highly subjective, so there won't be one objective answer to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many answers out there, and StackOverflow is not the best place to answer these questions, and you will need to learn a lot about it until you can make something nice (but you will, if you work enough). To answer your points, there is never one true answer, but anyway:

1. Game is something visual (unless you are writing a text-based game), you'll need good object-oriented programming skills and a thinking that will associate objects at your code level with your actual objects on screen. Most games have loops that handle physics/draw objects every second for many frames.
2. For a professional game, you'll be needing a framework/tool to develop. It's hard to write barebone Objective-C code and make a game out of it.
3. Yes, it is possible, but hard.
4. For 2D, have a look at Cocos2D and Flash, and using Box2D physics engine is a good idea. For 3D, I recommend Unity.
5. Not one specific I can think of, just search over the web, there are TONS of resources. Everyone understands concepts differently, so one 'super tutorial' of someone may be the 'worse' tutorial for another. Just search until you find a one you understand clearly.
6. Theoretically, yes, games can run purely using Objective-C, but most of the tools that help creating games use other languages too.

Comment: HI, thanks a lot for answering and clearing my doubts..  I think these information will suffice for me to start my Game :) thanks a lot..